# Will Amazon charge for the launching and terminating time of the cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

When I spawn a cluster on Amazon EMR, it takes some time to launch. If I terminate the cluster before it gets created, do I get charged at all.
The cluster also takes some time to terminate. Suppose I terminate the cluster at 58 minutes and the cluster takes an additional 5 minutes to terminate. Do I get charged for 1 hour or 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EMR has two cost components: Amazon EC2 and Amazon EMR

Both are charged based upon the running time of the Amazon EC2 instances. So, you will be charged for the number of 60-minute periods that each Amazon EC2 instance was running (rounded up).

In your example, if you terminated the cluster at 58 minutes but the instances were still shown as "running" beyond 60 minutes, they would be charged for an additional hour.

If you are using [Auto Scaling for EMR clusters](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-scaling-for-emr-clusters/), instances will automatically remain running until the end of the billing hour (giving extra capacity at no extra charge, through to the end of the hour).